# Android listener bindings (XML) are not executed

Tags: android, data-binding, android-edittext, kotlin, android-databinding

I have a custom `RecyclerAdapter` with the following `ViewHolder` class which is binding two variables to the view:

```
inner class ViewHolder(private val binding: ViewDataBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    fun bind(obj: Any) {
        binding.setVariable(BR.viewHolder, this)
        binding.setVariable(BR.obj, obj)
        binding.executePendingBindings()
    }

    fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
        Log.i("test", "Change is here!")
    }

    fun onTextClicked() {
        Log.i("test", "Click is here!")
    }
}
```

And this corresponding (minnimal) view:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<data>

    <variable
        name="holder"
        type="(...).adapters.ContactPropertyRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder" />

    <variable
        name="obj"
        type="(...).models.Address" />
</data>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/streetEditText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="@{obj.street}"
        android:onTextChanged="@{(s, start, before, count) -> holder.onTextChanged(s, start, before, count)}"
        android:onClick="@{() -> holder.onTextClicked()}"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Neither of the two functions seems to be triggered as i can tell from the Log. There is no error thrown. And AndroidStudio is recognizing the usages of both functions.

The `obj` variable seems to work properly and i already tried using an extra class, with the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the variable `viewHolder`

```
binding.setVariable(BR.viewHolder, this)
```

while you only defined a `holder` variable.

Thus `holder` is always `null`.

Comment: You are right, that must have been the issue. But I can't test it any more, since I completely refactored and removed all bindings.